# Spring @ExceptionHandler is not overriding the default response

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

Im trying to override the default response of Exceptions on Spring Rest, inserting a entity list:

**on @RestController:**

```
@ExceptionHandler(EntityConflictException.class)
public ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> exceptionHandler(EntityConflictException exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getList(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

**The Exception:**

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public class EntityConflictException extends RuntimeException {

    List<Entity> entities;

    public EntityConflictException(List<Entity> entities) {
        super("message");
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public EntityConflictException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public EntityConflictException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public List<Entity> getList() {
        return entities;
    }
}
```

**Exception throw on @Service:**

```
throw new EntityConflictException(entitiesList);
```

**The response is always:**

```
 {
    "timestamp": "2021-03-27 20:15:36",
    "status": 409,
    "error": "Conflict",
    "exception": "EntityConflictException",
    "message": "Conflict",
    "path": "/endpoint"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is I was passing a hibernate entity to the ResponseEntity. Then it occurred the classic error "failed to lazily initialize", but nothing was shown on the console about that. I had to debug to find out.

The error happens in ServletInvocableHandlerMethod at line 113

Answer (score 0):

I think you must remove `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)` from EntityConflictException. It is registered as a defalut handler for that Exception and it does not use your custom exception handling method.

Take a look at that article here [spring boot exception handling](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) and you will understand that those 2 exception handling ways that you use, are not meant to be used together. It is also pointed that using `@ResponseStatus` you can't override the message of the error.

Comment: I tried to remove and the only difference was the status (changed to 500 - internal server error). I have to tell you that my @ExceptionHandler is running (with ResponseStatus or not), I confirmed debugging. But is not showing my ResponseEntity.

Comment: The same happens with @ControllerAdvice

Comment: @VictorSoares please also post your controller and the relevant part of service to see what fails. if you have removed @ResponseStatus and you receive error 500 it means that the following method is not executed or not considered  `return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getList(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);`